# JavaScript Query

Tags: javascript

I have a field named "GROSS AMOUNT"

If the gross amount is zero, then the javascript message confirmation asks the user whether the user should continue saving with zero amount and if the user presses cancel, even the server side save button should not be active, it should return back to the panel of the gross amount.

I have used the following code for the client side.

```
function show_confirm() {

    // var txttemp = document.getElementById("<%=txtSAmt.ClientID %>").value;
    var menu = $find("<%= this.txtSAmt.ClientID %>");
    var check;
    if (menu != null) {
        check = menu.get_value();
    }
    if (check == '0') {
        var r = window.confirm("Gross Settlement Amount is 0.Press Cancel to Change, Press OK to save anyway");
        if (r == 'false') {

        }

    }

}
```

Please let me know that if the client clicks cancel, it should not fire the btnSave on the server side.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to know what should i include in r==false which would prevent my server side button event from firing

Comment: Is this asp.net?  MVC asp.net? Servlets?

Comment: try: `if(window.confirm("Gross Settlement Amount is 0.Press Cancel to Change, Press OK to save anyway")) { /* code */ } else { /* code */ }`

Comment: btnaddsettlement is getting fired for both OK and Cancel even if i write the above code.

Comment: My question is :

  <asp:Button ID="btnAddSettlement" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="Save_Button_Inactive"
                                                    ValidationGroup="vgSettlement" OnClick="btnAddSettlement_Click" OnClientClick="show_confirm()"/>


here on the cancel of confirm message box I dont want the btnAddSettlement_CLick to be clicked, which is getting fired irrespective of the cancel returning false.

How to do that?

Comment: Javascript code just to close down the message box without any changes in the page. ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is an event handler for the onclick event of `btnSave`.

First, `r` will *never* equal `"false"` because `confirm()` returns a boolean, not a string.  You need to compare `r` to `false` (without quotes).  Actually, you don't need to compare `r` to anything since `r` is already a boolean.  So `r == false` is the same as `!r`.

You can use `e.preventDefault()`.  You'll need to add the `e` parameter to your function definition:

```
function  show_confirm (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    ...
    if (check == '0') {
        var r = window.confirm("...");  
        if (!r) {
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            e.returnValue = false;
        }  
    }  
}
```

If you are calling `show_confirm()` like this:

```
<asp:button ... OnClientClick="show_confirm()" />
```

You'll need to change that to pass the `event` object:

```
<asp:button ... OnClientClick="show_confirm(event)" />
```

Alternatively, you can just return `false` from your event handler.  Again, if you are calling `show_confirm()` as above, you'll need to change it to:

```
<asp:button ... OnClientClick="return show_confirm()" />
```

You can change your function to this:

```
function show_confirm() {
    var menu = $find("<%= this.txtSAmt.ClientID %>");
    var check;
    if (menu != null) {
        check = menu.get_value();
    }
    return check != "0" || !confirm("Gross Settlement Amount is 0. Press Cancel to Change, Press OK to save anyway.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `show_confirm()` is being run for the `submit` event for the form:

```
    var r = window.confirm("Gross Settlement Amount is 0.Press Cancel to Change, Press OK to save anyway");
    return r;//if they confirm this will return true and if they cancel then this will return false and the form won't submit
```

Also to select an element by ID you don't need the `find()` function:

Change:

```
var menu = $find("<%= this.txtSAmt.ClientID %>");
```

To:

```
var menu = $("<%= this.txtSAmt.ClientID %>");//this is assuming that `this.txtSAmt.ClientID` starts with a hash (#)
```

And you can get the value of the `menu` element with the `.val()` function in jQuery:

```
var menu  = $("<%= this.txtSAmt.ClientID %>"),
    check = menu.val();
```

Comment: Javascript code just to close down the message box without any changes in the page. ?????

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the client must confirm this before moving forward, just wrap the responses in an if statement where if they click cancel it returns false, i.e. doesn't move forward with the response else if the click ok it returns true and lets the post continue which triggers the server side actions.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!r) { return false; }` ought to do it, based on what little information you've provided.